# make an empty ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a function that makes an ajax request to write some data to a database.
Yet, when for some reason, the function is called more than once on the page (which sometimes seems to happen), I check via javascript how often the function was called and the ajax request is not executed if it was called more than once to avoid adding data twice.

However, since the ajax request is never executed in this case, the .done function does not work anymore, which breaks the functionality of the script further down the line.

My workaround is, if the function was already called, to make an 'empty' ajax request in which I do not transfer any data to the PHP script on the server-side.

This way, I can still use the .done function and execute the rest of script normally (without adding any duplicate data).

Is that a sensible way to deal with such a case?
It seems to me that it is a waste of server resources, since there is no need to communicate with the server in this case.

Is there a better way to make an "empty" ajax request, such that the .done function can still be executed?

Comment: is cache set to false in the ajax function?

Comment: Please edit your question and add a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code demonstrating the problem.